# Change children value from ng-model

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In below code, if we click on Div it will shows label children value in input box , from where i have to change label name,, but when i am trying to change the value it was removing remaining input text and all tags with the Div,, can u pls tell me how to solve this issue??

[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/L6kfOCihXv8QvykQ58xp?p=preview)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.textVal = 'click on User Name';

  $scope.selectedEvent = {};
$scope.setText = function (element) {
    $scope.selectedEvent = element;
    $scope.textVal = angular.element(element.currentTarget).find('label').html();

};
$scope.changeLabelText = function () {
  //  $scope.selectedEvent.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
    angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).html($scope.textVal);
   // $scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
};

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeLabelText($event)">//change user name here//
<div  ng-click="setText($event)">
  <label>User Name</label><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter username">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: not sure what you are trying to do

Comment: Please Explain Clearly..

Comment: @ArunPJohny check my demo once, where i am trying to change label name from input text box, but when i entered anything remaing input tags are removing in div tag

Comment: @user3141852 check my demo once, where i am trying to change label name from input text box, but when i entered anything remaing input tags are removing in div tag

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think a more jQueryish solution will be

```js
var app = angular.module('my-app', [], function() {})

app.controller('AppController', function($scope) {
  $scope.textVal = 'click on User Name';

  $scope.label = {
    userName: 'User Name'
  }

  $scope.setText = function(key) {
    $scope.currentKey = key;
    $scope.textVal = $scope.label[$scope.currentKey];
  };
  $scope.changeLabelText = function() {
    $scope.label[$scope.currentKey] = $scope.textVal;
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="my-app">
  <div ng-controller="AppController">
    <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" ng-change="changeLabelText()">
    <div ng-click="setText('userName')">
      <label>{{label.userName}}</label>
      <br/>
      <input type="text" placeholder="enter username">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.textVal = 'Username';

  $scope.selectedEvent = {};
$scope.setText = function (element) {
    $scope.selectedEvent = element;
    $scope.textVal = angular.element(element.currentTarget).find('label').html();

};
$scope.changeLabelText = function () {
  //  $scope.selectedEvent.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
    angular.element($scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget).html($scope.textVal);
   // $scope.selectedEvent.currentTarget.innerHTML = $scope.textVal;
};

 });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app='myapp'>

  <head>
    <script data-require="jquery@*" data-semver="2.1.4" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.8" data-semver="1.4.8" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.8/angular.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" >
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <input type="text" ng-model="textVal" >//change user name here//
<div  ng-click="setText($event)">
  <label>{{textVal}}</label><br/>
  <input type="text" placeholder="enter username" ng-model="" ng-change="changeLabelText($event)">
</div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: @Vijju Sena please explain more.

Comment: if i clicked on username DIV,, have to show label name of that div has to show to input textbox,, where i have to change that label name,, if i change name in text box, label name also should be changed..

Comment: maybe change   <label>{{textVal}}</label><br/>

Comment: when change second input value change label value. is this your purpose?

Comment: @habiJB no no first input

Comment: @habiJZ have to show label name to the input box on clikc only,,, u have placed directly.. my requirement is have to show label names in the div has to show in input box on click only